# Are Enderman slaves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are the Enderman really slaves to the Ender Dragon?  I was researching them and I read that they had been subjugated to slavery under the ender dragon and that they are virtually insane.

Comment: Where did you read that? And if your source is legitimate, why ask it here?

Comment: This looks like a [Reddit theory](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/wdqhw/enslaved_enderman_theory/), and imho it's just a speculation or developer's intent, nothing we can really answer for sure.

Comment: VTLO. I think an answer stating there's nothing in the official canon that supports that would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official "lore" to the Minecraft game at this point, only theories. The official [Minecraft wiki](https://loreofminecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Minecraft_Lore_Wiki) has entries for the game(s), but none contain any information; opting to delete the entries instead.

> ### Minecraft
>
> Delete because its fan-fiction and non-canon

This is because there is no information about the in-game monsters, creatures, etc, beyond their technical aspects.

Basically, as far as I am aware, the only "official lore" about the game is things like the fact that the Creeper only came about because of a code error in the generation of the pig.

Anything beyond this, while *exciting* is entirely theory, which is not something we handle here on Arqade.

Comment: Alright thx.  I had no idea whether or not this was just ran theory.  Thx for the response!  What area of stack exchange would be appropriate for such a question on fan theory?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't think there really is a place on the SE network. Since it's fan theory, there is a big allowance for discussion and development. It would be better off on a forum or discussion site. Maybe go ask on the [Arqade Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), you might some people willing to talk about it there

Comment: If you can think of something substantial, you might post it to [AO3](https://archiveofourown.org/) or another fanfiction site. AO3's Minecraft content is basically all Dream [RPF](https://fanlore.org/wiki/RPF) at this point, so you wouldn't exactly have a lot of competition...